# Por qué mi gráfica en movimiento me sale en distintas imágenes? PYTHON

Tags: matplotlib, animación

estoy intentando hacer una gráfica de dispersión y que aparezca un punto y se vaya, aparezca e siguiente y se vaya etc.
Con el código que os adjunto, se me aparece en distintas imágenes, sin embargo había leído que de esta forma se reproducía una animación.
No se si mi fallo está en el código o está en que con un bucle no se puede hacer.

```
for _ in range(2164):  
    for dest, elem in zip(d_u, usuario):
        if (elem == usuario_teclado):
            for x, y, dc in zip(CX, CY, d_xy):
                if(dest == dc):
                   x_m = int(x)
                   y_m = int(y)
                   X.append(x_m)
                   Y.append(y_m)
                   d_xym = str(dc) 
                   etiqueta.append(d_xym)
                   plt.xlim(minx,maxx)
                   plt.ylim(miny,maxy)
                   plt.scatter(x_m,y_m, marker ='o') 
                   plt.pause(0.001)
                   plt.clf()
plt.show()
```

Siendo CX y CY dos listas con coordenadas y d_xy los nombres asociados con cada coordenada.

Pd: para la animación no me puedo descargar ninguna librería externa como pandas-alive o ffmpeg, por eso estoy buscando alguna alternativa.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando pones el `plt.show()` lo que haces es crear una imagen fija. Para hacer una animación tendrías que importar la biblioteca `matplotlib.animation`, que sirve para hacer animaciones, lo único que no se es si te servirá para hacer aparecer y desaparecer puntos, quiero decir, yo sólo lo he utilizado para funciones continuas y no se mucho más, pero espero haberte ayudado.